# Can't run app on iPhone 4.2.1 with Xcode 4.3.1 and IOS

Tags: iphone, ios, sdk

I hope someone can help :) It's been troubling me for a while, this one.

I'm running Xcode 4.3.1 with base SDK iOS 5.1.
iPhone version is 4.2.1, an old 3S model I believe.

When hitting Run, Xcode compiles fine and says that it's running my app on the phone. Everything appears like it works, but the app does not launch on the phone. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong here? The app works fine in the simulator.

Also when I try to run the app on a 4S, version 5.1, Xcode says: "Xcode cannot run using the selected device. No provisioned iOS devices are available with a compatible iOS version. Connect an iOS device with a recent enough version of iOS to run your application or choose an iOS simulator as the destination.".

Comment: O silly me - figured it out now :)

I had not built for armv6 with regards to the old 3S iPhone.
I had not enabled developer on the 4S iPhone via Organizer.

Answer (score 5):

You need to add `armv7` and `armv6` architectures both to the Architectures and you need to do this as armv6 is architecture supported by devices older than iPhone 3GS and hence if you need to compile or give support to devices prior than iPhone 3GS, you need to add `armv6` to your architectures as shown below:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: @DanKronholm: Dd my answer help you?

Comment: @lk_vc: Yes sorry that was a mistake. I have edited the answer now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution... :)

Build it for armv6 too.