# Developing with Xcode 4.3 for iOS 4.2.1

Tags: ios4, xcode4.3

I created a new project and set the compiler to LLVM GCC 4.2, iOS deployment target to 4.2 but I still can't launch it on an iPhone 3G with 4.2.1 on it. It works fine in the simulator and on an iPhone 4, but when I run it on an iPhone 3G with 4.2.1 it simple "finishes" right after I start it, without any console output.

Does anyone have a clue what's wrong?

These are the valid architectures:

[image: Valid architectures]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finds the item require the plist and removes the restriction to only ARMv7

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: I'm sorry the item to try on. plist file is: Required device capabilities

Comment: OK got it, thanks! This should be it :-) There was only "armv6" in it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add armv6 architecture to the Valid Architectures.
See this answer:
[Can't run app on iPhone 4.2.1 with Xcode 4.3.1 and IOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9823142/cant-run-app-on-iphone-4-2-1-with-xcode-4-3-1-and-ios)

Comment: No luck, armv6 is already in the list (see original posting)…

Answer (score 1):

`Valid Architectures` is of no use. You need to change `Architectures` to `armv6 armv7`, and `Build Active Architectures` to `NO`. [image: demo]

Answer (score 1):

In your project settings,

click on TARGET,

There should be a item called Required device capabilities.  set that to armv6

it worked on me

Answer (score 0):

Changing the Architectures to armv6 armv7 worked for me, I didn't need the Required Device Capabilities at all.