# Run iOS-App from Xcode 4.3.3 on an iPod Touch 2nd Generation with iOS 4.2.1

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4, ipod-touch

I am trying to run an App on an arm6 iDevice but I can't see or run it in the schemes.

[image]

I think it's nearly the same problem as in [Can't run app on iPhone 4.2.1 with Xcode 4.3.1 and IOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9823142/cant-run-app-on-iphone-4-2-1-with-xcode-4-3-1-and-ios) but this answer didn't work for me.

Comment: Is the device set up for Development? You need to go into the Organiser and ensure the device is ready for Development and also UUID added to a valid provisioning profile for your app

Comment: plug your iPod touch 2G, and change the app info list - device capability to armv6 (delete armv7), in build info, add armv6 too.

Comment: Well when you plug it, open "Windows" - "organizer", and setup for development, as Suhail Patel mentioned.

Comment: I just hit "Use for Development" in the organizer. Where do I have to add the UUID? Also in the Organizer?

Comment: Here's a tutorial I wrote some time ago:[Running iOS 5 build apps on the orignal iPhone, iPod touch and iPhone 3G](http://triplesoftware.nl/2011/12/running-ios-5-build-apps-on-the-orignal-iphone-ipod-touch-and-iphone-3g/)

Comment: Thanks everyone. I think storyboard is the problem.